# How to detect if an ASP ComboBox is blank.empty

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, combobox

I have an ASP ComboBox that is populated on page load with a list of information and a selected index is set. I want the user to be able to type a new value into the box and run a routine that saves that value.

So far, I've managed to set it so when you run the save routine it can detect the text of the box using;

```
cboFreeBody.SelectedItem.Text
```

If the box loads with 'arm' and I change it to 'leg', when I run my routine it grabs the new value and processes it, however if I delete 'arm' and leave it blank when I run the routine the above code returns 'arm', where I'd expect it to return ''.

I'm sorry if I haven't explained myself fully here, I'm rather new to ASP and VB.NET so I'm probably just splurting useless information here, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ma not sure but thats might help you..

```
If com_box.SelectedItem = vbEmpty Then
            MsgBox("its empty")
        End If
```

Comment: I tried this but it wouldn't allow me to do it, reports that operator '=' is not identified for types 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem'

and com_box.SelectedItem.Text is just causing the same issue.

Comment: If ListBox1.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("empty")
        End If

Comment: This doesn't work because .Text never = "" The previous value is persistent when I try to use a null value.

Answer (score 0):

I use the isnullorwhitespace function usually.

```
if string.isnullorwhitespace(cboFreeBody.SelectedItem.Text) then

else

end if
```